# Wrong "taxonomist" badge received

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

I just received a notification on the SU site that I was awarded a "Taxonomist" badge for the "autocomplete" tag.

The problem is that I did not create the "autocomplete" tag. Actually none of the 8 questions I asked is using "autocomplete"?

Bug in the Matrix? Something to do with an answer I made to a question that had the "autocomplete" tag (although I doubt it)?

Comment: Did you edit a question with the [autocomplete] tag by any accident? By the way... I might have caused this taxonomist badge as I recently retagged a question from [auto-complete] to [autocomplete].

Comment: Maybe, I can't remember all the questions I edited. But it's not recently, so it might be linked to you retagging the question. But shouldn't the original poster get the award, as (s)he created the tag?

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell, the system is giving you the badge due to this: https://superuser.com/posts/58514/revisions

However it was created earlier here: [why zsh git autocompletion is not as good as bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/40529)

This was due to a bug/missing feature in earlier versions of our codebase where the tag creator was not properly tracked in the Tags table when posting a question.